# Swing Bean Binding for tables in NetBeans

Tags: java, swing, desktop-application, beans-binding

I want to know how to filter data in a database table and insert into a swing table with bean binding in NetBeans. I read NetBeans beanbinding tutorial.But is not much helpful.(It shows how to load data directly from a database table)I want to know how to query and select relevant data and insert into the table.

Also, I want to know how to add data in text fields into table with Beanbinding in netbeans.I still code manually.

Also how to remove/delete a selected row/rows in Beansbinding and get data from table and do calculations(no of rows, total value in a particular column).?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swing Bean Binding in NetBeans](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318992/swing-bean-binding-in-netbeans)

Answer (score 1):

What about displaying fisrt some data in a JTable and, after, work with your database?

1°) Extend an [AbstractTableModel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html) that will represente your DB Table. This is a good and short [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/TablewithacustomTableModel.htm).

2°) Then, with the appropriate JDBC driver, you'll be able to execute your [Select queries](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/JDBCselect.htm) on your database and retrieve data.

3°) By firing right events through your AbstractTableModel (see [fireTableDataChanged()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableDataChanged%28%29)), your screen will be updated automaticaly

4°) About delete record(s): you need to work with the [selected](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#selectionModel) row(s). With it, you're able to reach your data (find primary key) and execute JDBC delete query. If and only if, your query is successfully executed, then update your internal data and fire events: [fireTableRowsDeleted(int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsDeleted%28int,%20int%29), [fireTableRowsInserted(int, int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableRowsInserted%28int,%20int%29), etc.

Good luck!